# Javascript, Find img src attribute in string and add function to it

Tags: javascript, string, angular, replace

I have html string to render with ng-bind-html in AngularJS, but I need to add ng-click function to every img I have.

This is the html string example:

```
$scope.html="<--some html content-->
             <img class='some-class' src='http://www.example.com/img/test.jpg'>
             <--some other html content-->"
```

and the return value should be like this:

```
"<--some html content-->
<img ng-click='openModal(http://www.example.com/img/test.jpg)' class='some-class' src='http://www.example.com/img/test.jpg'>
<--some other html content-->"
```

note: class can be any name

How can I get the image source so I can put it to openModal(some-url) function?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there will be multiple links. You can do an `ng-repeat` and associate the same link in the openModal and `src`. Something like this:
All your links go into links.

Then use an ng-repeat: `ng-repeat="link in links"
({{link}}) and ng-src={{link}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can approach javascript on click event bind

```
angular.element('body').on( 'click',"img", function() {
let src = angular.element(this).attr('src');
console.log('src', src);
});
```